# Obtaining Negative Variance. What is the error?

Tags: probability, variance, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose a dice is thrown $8$ times and success is considered as obtaining either a $5$ or $6$. What is the variance of the number of successes?

**Attempt:** Let the indicator variable $X_i$ be $1$ when either a $5$ or a $6$ turns up on the dice on the $i$th throw and let $X_i$ be $0$ otherwise.

Then: Expected number of successes = $\sum E(X_i)=8 \cdot P(\text{Success}) = 8 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3}$

If $X$ is the total number of success, $E(X^2)= \sum 1^2 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac {8}{3}$

> $Variance = \dfrac{8}{3}- \dfrac{8^2}{3^2} <0$

Where is the error?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, $X$ is binomial with $n=8,p=1/3$, so $\operatorname{var}(X)=np(1-p)=16/9$

In your solution, $E[X^2]$ is not correct. $$E[X^2]=\sum_{i=1}^8\sum_{j=1}^8 E[X_iX_j]=\sum_{i=1}^8 E[X_i^2]+\sum_{i\neq j} E[X_i]E[X_j]=8/3+56/9=80/9$$
So, $\operatorname{var}(X)=\frac{80}{9}-\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)^2=16/9$

Comment: Thank you for the answer